# Are PHP scripts run using the "php" command affected by the timeout limit?

Tags: php, timeout, cron

Are PHP scripts run using the "php" command affected by the timeout limit? I plan to schedule php scripts using cron.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, but you can set an unlimited timeout by adding this to the top of your script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: @john Flatness answer seems to be right. In my local XAMMP env I've tried setting the max_execution time to 10 seconds and ran the script via CLI it didn't produced any timeout issue.

Answer (score 14):

Some systems, such as Ubuntu, actually already start with separate CLI and Apache configurations in `/etc/php5`.

The relevant command in the ini file is:

```
max_execution_time = 30      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
```

However, if you are unable to modify the php.ini for whatever reason, you can create a new php.ini with configuration settings favourable to the command-line, and point to the file like so:

`php -c /path/to/ini/php.ini -f script.php`

Or, you can use Cailin's solution, and set the time limit at the top of the file - but if you are running on a server with PHP 'safe mode' enabled, then you will have to use your own ini file.

Comment: and the reason for the downvote is? kinda hard to improve things without feedback...

Comment: not sure but maybe the downvoter was looking for the contents of the custom configuration file

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, but my only thought was how do you tell if the server is in PHP safe mode.  Hope that helps @HorusKol

Answer (score 11):

Depends. If your php binary is the PHP CLI interface, the default `max_execution_time` is zero (meaning there is no limit).

On the other hand, if it's the older-style CGI binary, you will be affected by the `max_execution_time` limit, and you'll need to call `set_time_limit` to get rid of it (assuming you're not in the dreaded PHP safe mode).