# How to setup a timeout on PHP exec() command on Windows?

Tags: php

I am running some php exec commands on PHP - CLI
Some of these exec() take too long.

So my idea is to setup a 60 seconds timeout on the exec()

I found some solutions for Linux, but I could not adapt them on windows (pipe/processes...)

Any idea on how to trigger a timeout on windows php cli exec() command ?

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in timeout feature? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039224/are-php-scripts-run-using-the-php-command-affected-by-the-timeout-limit

Answer (score -1):

```
$intExecutionTimeout = 60;
$strCommand = 'wget http://google.com';

$strCommand = 'timeout --signal=15 --kill-after=' . ( $intExecutionTimeout* 2 ) . 's ' . $intExecutionTimeout . 's ' . $strCommand . ' &';

exec( $strCommand, $arrstrResponse );
```

Comment: Code only answers may provide the answer to the problem, but an explanation helps a lot in understanding what you've changed and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

try timeout command in CLI:

```
$time = 60;
$command = 'wget http://google.com';
exec(sprintf("C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t %d %s", $time, $command), $output);
```

Comment: I tried that on windows (with a sleep.bat that sleeps for 30 seconds) and put $time=10: NOT GOOD ! 
Timeout is printed after 30 seconds and not after 10 seconds !
and I use gitBash command on windows so I have timeout available.

Comment: timeout: unknown option -- t
I guess you are refering to -k, hower the post is about Windows, not Linux

Comment: `C:\windows\system32\timeout` or `C:\windows\system32\timeout.exe` ?